# How to avoid duplicates in nested foreach loop php

Tags: php, codeigniter, loops, foreach, nested

Why are values are getting printed multiple times (see images below). I need to print them only once.

```
<?php foreach($patchData3 as $tes3){?> 
    <?php foreach($patchData1 as $tes){?>
        <tr class="<?php if($tes->PATCH == $tes3->PATCH) {echo "red_color"; } ?>"> 
            <td><?php echo $tes->HOSTNAME;?></td>
            <td><?php echo $tes->VERSION;?></td> 
            <td><?php echo $tes->PATCH;?></td> <!--bgcolor="#FF0000"-->
        </tr>   
    <?php } ?>
<?php }?>
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: It would help know the value of these arrays/objects you're passing around, along with your current and expected results.

Comment: Its just simple string values.

Comment: You have a `foreach` within `foreach`. What do you expect?

Comment: Well we are mostly interested in their number. You are basically saying for each **Array1** I want to loop EVERY item from **Array2**. If that's what you want then you're doing it right.

Comment: Give an example of input and expected output. :)

Comment: I have array1 with all the list of hostname, version, patch and in array2 we have old patch details. If array1 patch match with array2, it should show in red color text in an table.

Comment: I have added image, please have a look

Comment: Well you have **echo** inside your `foreach` that is inside another `foreach` why are you surprised it's printing them many times? I think you want to do the checking above your **echos** and if a mismatch occurs just change change some `var` and echo the `var` as class that gives *color: red;*

Comment: Do you have any other way to do this and avoid duplicating?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php foreach($patchData1 as $tes){ ?>          
    <tr class="<?php if(checkfunction($tes->PATCH,$patchData3) == TRUE) { echo "red_color"; } ?>"> 
        <td><?php echo $tes->HOSTNAME;?></td>
        <td><?php echo $tes->VERSION;?></td> 
        <td><?php echo $tes->PATCH;?></td> <!--bgcolor="#FF0000"-->
    </tr>   
<?php } ?>

<?php 
    function checkfunction($patch,$patchData3){
        foreach($patchData3 as $tes3){
            if($patch == $tes3->PATCH){
                return true;
            }   
        }
    }
?>
```

I used a function to overcome the duplication. Please comment if it does not work.

Comment: A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: patchData3